# LINQ to XML: Don't Create XAttribute if value is DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, xattribute

I am querying a database using C# and creating a `DataTable`. From this `DataTable` I am using LINQ to XML to create an XML file.

My problem is that for null columns in the data table, when I call SetAttributeValue on an element, it creates a blank attribute. `SetAttributeValue(name, value)` doesn't add the attribute at all if value is `null`. Is there a way to mimic this behavior for `DBNull.Value`? I don't want to check every single row and column to see if the value equals `DBNull.Value`.

Expected:

```
<Root>
    <Element1 E1="Test"/>
</Root>
```

Actual:

```
<Root>
    <Element1 E1="Test" E2=""/>
</Root>
```

Code for Element1:

```
DataTable testTable = new DataTable();
testTable.Columns.Add("E1");
testTable.Columns.Add("E2");

testTable.Rows.Add("Test", DBNull.Value);

XElement element = new XElement("Element1");

element.SetAttributeValue("E1", testTable.AsEnumerable().Select(item => item["E1"]));
element.SetAttributeValue("E2", testTable.AsEnumerable().Select(item => item["E2"]));

return element;
```

Comment: will you add the XML file with expected and not-expected behavior.

Comment: could you show the code that does the transformation from DataTable to Xml?

Answer (score 1):

Write yourself an extension method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void SetAttributeValueEx(this XElement source, XName name, object value)
    {
        if (value == DBNull.Value) value = null;
        source.SetAttributeValue(name, value);
    }
}
```